# Homology group calculation of Klein Bottle is not a free product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I'm attempting to calculate the homology groups of the Klein Bottle. I used the fundamental polygon below, from which $\partial_2(u)=-a-b+c,\partial_2(L)=-a+b-c,\partial_1(a)=0=\partial_1(b)=\partial_1(c)=0$. Calculating $H_2$ is easier, but when calculating $H_1$, I find $Z_1=\langle a,b,c\rangle,B_1=\langle -a-b+c,-a+b-c\rangle$, so
\begin{align}
H_1&\cong\langle a,b,c\ |\ -a-b+c,-a+b-c\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b,c\ |\ 2a,-a+b-c\rangle\\
&\cong\langle a,b\ |\ 2a\rangle\\
&\cong\mathbb{Z}*(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})
\end{align}

But the homology group is $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ according to a bunch of sources, so what did I do wrong?

[image: Klein Bottle fundamental polygon]

Comment: It's an abelian group. So if you wanna argue in terms of generators and relations, you better do it within the category of abelian groups. Otherwise, you have to add the commutation relations to everything in sight.